# Is it safe to store secret files in a public AWS S3 bucket with a random key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Even if S3 bucket is public, it cannot be accessed without knowing the key. This is what I know.

I have stored images that contain personal information of users with random keys like `/secret/F0EBAA71F7131E.jpg` in a public S3 bucket.

Is there a possibility of data leakage if it's stored in this way? How can it be leaked, if possible?

Comment: Its not a good idea to store private info in public buckets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply creating objects with random names? No, obfuscation is not good security.

From [Security through obscurity - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity):

> Security experts have rejected this view as far back as 1851, and advise that obscurity should never be the only security mechanism.

It is possible to [back-trace random number generation](http://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2016-September/030231.html) (it is very difficult to generate truly random numbers), or guess very large key spaces. Worse yet, if a listing of the objects were available, all objects become compromised.

You should consider a more robust security method.

Comment: I would add that many bad guys are scanning S3 names paces to find open buckets and key names.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for a safer method.